# Ionic: NavParams in a child tab is lost after a page refresh

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, navigation, navparams

Consider a parent TabsPage with IonicPage() decorator as such:

```
@IonicPage({
    segment: 'case/:caseId/summary/:summaryId'
})
```

Pass the `navParams` of the TabsPage as `rootParams` to all the child tabs pages.

Navigate to the child tab and log the navParams instance in constructor. Also log navParams instance in parent TabsPage constructor.

```
export class TabsPage {
  constructor(private _navParams: NavParams){
    console.log(this._navParams);
  }
}

export class AboutPage {
  constructor(private _navParams: NavParams){
    console.log(this._navParams);
  }
}
```

In a normal flow, when one navigates from a different page to one of the child pages of the tabs navigation, passing `{caseId: 123, summaryId: 234}` as navParams, you'll see the same navParams being logged in both parent and child's constructor.

```
export class LandingPage{
   goToTabsPage() {
     this.navCtrl.push("TabsPage", {caseId: 123, summaryId: 2345});
   }
}
```

However, if you are in the child tab and hit browser reload, you'll see the navParams `{caseId: 123, summaryId: 234}` in the parent TabsPage constructor but not in the child tab.

```
export class TabsPage {
      constructor(private _navParams: NavParams){
        console.log(this._navParams);
      }
    }
```

//This prints `{caseId: 123, summaryId: 234}`

```
export class AboutPage {
  constructor(private _navParams: NavParams){
    console.log(this._navParams);
  }
}
```

//This prints `{}`

Is this an Ionic bug or am I missing something?